# Parameterizing the Cucumber feature files

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I am having a Spring Java application with Cucumber feature files to run selenium test case.
Now I need to dynamically parametrize the feature files. So I am building an application which exposes all the parameters in feature files on UI
Users will modify these parameters. Once modified the selenium test cases should run by picking these new parameters. 
Kindly advise

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more in detail what you want to achieve? Where he parameters in the feature file would be needed?

Comment: Let me give an example: Say I have a login page and username is admin and password is admin & a feature file and selenium to test the same. The feature file in parameterised and I pass 2 scenarios to test. First is the correct one i.e username & password = admin & admin. Second is error scenario. i.e username & password = admin & user. Now lets say I need to test third scenario i.e username & password = admin & Admin. This has to be done dynamically. So I am giving the UI for user to enter the scenario & override the feature file then execute the test case.

Comment: You mean you want to execute the same feature file in automatic mode (admin/admin and admin/user) and in interactive mode? From the IDE?

Comment: Yes something on similar lines

Comment: @SubOptimal any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: From my POV it's possible, but in your back-end, you will have to regenerate the feature file using specflow.exe(cucumber) and then rebuild the solution using msbuild, after that you can use MSTest or what ever you are using to run the tests. If that's what you mean I can write a little bit more detailed answer on how to achieve it (I havn't done it myself but I can see it hapenning)